# Geotools filterfactory not found exception

Tags: java, geotools, sparklines

Can anyone help me out of this exception.

In a geotools query program i am using

Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("CONTAINS(the_geom,POINT(-115.56,67.567))");

and when am running the program using spark(sbt) ..it is throwing exception as follows can anyone help me....

Exception in thread "main" org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: No factory of kind "FilterFactory" found.
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:375)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:145)
        at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.lookup(CommonFactoryFinder.java:346)
        at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.java:300)
        at geocode.feature.FeatureExtraction.findShapefile(FeatureExtraction.java:64)
at geocode.batch.GeocodeMain$.main(GeocodeMain.scala:33)
at geocode.batch.GeocodeMain.main(GeocodeMain.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)

at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (and other similar errors) always means that you forgot to add a jar to your runtime classpath (and probably your build). To be sure which one is missing I'd need to see your mvn pom.xml but I suspect it is either `gt-cql` or possibly `gt-main` or `gt-api`.

You might also like to read my [blog post](http://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/maven/dependencies/2015/04/15/FindingGeoToolsJars.html) discussing how to find which jar to look in for a class using [joops](https://code.google.com/p/joops/).

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue got resolved, when we passed all three geotools library as jars (--jars) in spark-submit